# How to derive the characteristic function $\phi_X(t) = \mathbb{E}\left(e^{it^T X}\right) = e^{it^T \mu} e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^T\Sigma t}$?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, characteristic-functions

My attempt to calculate the characteristic function $\mathbb{E}\left(e^{it^T X}\right)$ of multivariate normal distributed $X \sim \mathcal{N}_d(\mu,\Sigma)$, finding a lecture note that writes as follows, but I am confused about the $\overset{?}{=}$ step.

\begin{align*}
\phi_X(t) &= \mathbb{E}\left(e^{it^T X}\right) \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{it^T X} f_X(x) dx \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{it^T X} \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{d/2}|\Sigma|^{1/2}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu)} dx \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{d/2}|\Sigma|^{1/2}} \exp{\left(-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)+it^T x\right)} dx \\
&\overset{?}{=} \exp{\left(it^T \mu - \frac{1}{2} t^T \Sigma t\right)} \\
&= e^{it^T \mu} e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^T\Sigma t}
\end{align*}

Can you show me more details about that step?

Answer (score 5):

What they do is completing the square:

\begin{align}-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)+it^T x & = -\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)+it^T (x - \mu)  + it^T \mu \\
& = -\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)+it^T (x - \mu)  +\frac{1}{2} t^T \Sigma t - \frac{1}{2} t^T \Sigma t\\ & \;\;\;\; +\ it^T \mu \\
& = -\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)+it^T \Sigma \Sigma^{-1} (x - \mu)  +\frac{1}{2} t^T \Sigma \Sigma^{-1}\Sigma t \\ & \;\;\;\; - \frac{1}{2} t^T \Sigma t +\ it^T \mu \\
& = -\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu-i\Sigma t)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu-i\Sigma t) - \frac{1}{2} t^T \Sigma t +\ it^T \mu
\end{align}

Then, the two last terms factorize out with the exponential, while the first gives rise to a reparametrized Gaussian. So that integral is 1.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how you came from the second last to last line? 
$
\begin{align*}
-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)+it^T \Sigma \Sigma^{-1} (x - \mu)  +\frac{1}{2} t^T \Sigma \Sigma^{-1}\Sigma t  - \frac{1}{2} t^T \Sigma t +\ it^T \mu =
\\
\\
-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu-i\Sigma t)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu-i\Sigma t) - \frac{1}{2} t^T \Sigma t +\ it^T \mu
\end{align*}
$

Comment: The second term is equal to $\frac{1}{2}it^T \Sigma \Sigma^{-1} (x - \mu) + \frac{1}{2}i(x - \mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} \Sigma  t$.

Comment: @Raskolnikov, Why? And what does it give to us? Even if I put that equation, which is equal to the second term, as you said, I get to terms, one of which contains ((x−μ)^T−it^TΣ) and another contains (i(x−μ)^T−t^TΣ), so, anyways I cant get, how did you get over it

Comment: @Timur: I'm not sure what you are struggling with. Note that $$\left[it^T \Sigma \Sigma^{-1} (x - \mu)\right]^T = it^T \Sigma \Sigma^{-1} (x - \mu)) = (x - \mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} i\Sigma t \; .$$ The first equality is correct because a number (1x1 matrix) transposed is equal to itself. The second is just mechanically applying the transposition rule to a product.